# Let $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{2k+1}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AB=0$, Prove that $|(A+A^T)(B+B^T)|=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{2k+1}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AB=0$, prove that $\det[(A+A^T)(B+B^T)]=0\ \ $   with $ \ k\in \mathbb{N}$

I don't have ideas for this problem. Thanks !

Comment: This is not true for even $n$: Take $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}=B$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The key is to show that the rank of at least one of the two matrices is at most $k$. Once this is shown, use the facts that $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(C+D)\le\operatorname{rank}(C)+\operatorname{rank}(D)$ to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

W.L.O.G $\det B=0$
$\operatorname{rank}[(A+A^T)(B+B^T)]=\operatorname{rank}[AB+AB^T+A^T(B+B^T)]=\operatorname{rank}[AB^T+A^T(B+B^T)] \le \operatorname{rank}(AB^T)+\operatorname{rank}[A^T(B+B^T)] \le \operatorname{rank}B^T+\operatorname{rank}A^T=\operatorname{rank}A+\operatorname{rank}B \le (2k+1)+\operatorname{rank}AB=2k+1$

So that, if equality occurs then $\operatorname{rank}(AB^T)=\operatorname{rank}A$

but $\det B^T=\det B=0$ shown $ \operatorname{rank}(AB^T)<\operatorname{rank}A$

Thus, $\operatorname{rank}[(A+A^T)(B+B^T)]<2k+1$ , we have done.

p/s: instead of $2k + 1$, problem also true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: The conclusion $\det B=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $rank(AB^T)<rank(A)$ is not valid in general (take $A=0$ for instance).

Comment: Thanks you. Can you tell me the solution of this problem?